How can I increase the gap between the values of the x axis in a line chart and also change its width and height?
I just started using charts js in react and I wanted to know that can  I increase the gap between the values of the x axis in a line chart and also in need to change the width and height of the chart.
import React from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import Linechartstyle from './Linechart.module.css';

ChartJS.register(
    CategoryScale,
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Title,
    Tooltip,
  );

  export const options = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
  };
  
const labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'];
  
export const data = {
    labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Coins',
        data: [105, 59, 80, 18, 190],
        borderColor: '#34b2fe',
        backgroundColor: '#34b2fe',
      },
    ],
};

function Linechart() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Line options={options} data={data} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Linechart

I need to increase this gap and change the width and height
To increase the width and height I added the height and width css property to the <Line /> block but It didn't work.

Did you try to define the width and height of the enclosing div through CSS?
